# Output of command as input in MySQL-query

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

I'm trying to use the output of a bash command as an input variable for a sql-query:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --user=root --password=root database << QUERY_INPUT

#Get temp from sensor.
current_temp=$(sed -n 2,2p /sys/bus/w1/devices/xxx/w1_slave | awk '{print $10}' | awk -F= '{print $2}')

#SQL query
INSERT INTO temperatures (tdate, ttime, temperature)
VALUES (CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$current_temp')
QUERY_INPUT
```

Im getting:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_temp=24750

```
INSERT INTO temperatures (tdate, ttime, temperature)
VALUES' at line 1"
```

How can I pass only the numbers to the query?

Comment: What are you trying to extract from `/sys/bus/w1/devices/xxx/w1_slave`? That line looks like it could be simplified greatly

Comment: xxx is just a serial number for a DS18B20 temperature sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
current_temp=$(sed -n 2,2p /sys/bus/w1/devices/xxx/w1_slave | awk '{print $10}' | awk -F= '{print $2}')
mysql --user=root --password=root database -e "INSERT INTO temperatures (tdate, ttime, temperature) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,$current_temp)"
```

I can unfortunately not test it at the moment

Comment: Thank you (and the other guys answering), that worked perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The command that sets `current_temp` is not part of the SQL output. Move it outside the here document.

Only code meant to be passed to `mysql` can appear in the here document, which means you need to move the command that sets `current_temp`, and all shell comments, outside the here document.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get temp from sensor.
current_temp=$(sed -n 2,2p /sys/bus/w1/devices/xxx/w1_slave | awk '{print $10}' | awk -F= '{print $2}')

mysql --user=root --password=root database << QUERY_INPUT
INSERT INTO temperatures (tdate, ttime, temperature)
VALUES (CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$current_temp')
QUERY_INPUT
```

As mentioned in the comments, there are several ways to simplify setting `current_temp`. A sample:

1. Use a single `awk` command:

   ```
   current_temp=$( awk 'NR==2 {print $10}' /sys/bus/w1/devices/xxx/w1_slave )
   ```
2. Use pure `bash`:

   ```
    { read; read -a fields; current_temp=${fields[9]}; } < /sys/bus/w1/devices/xxx/w1_slave
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO temperatures (tdate, ttime, temperature)
VALUES (CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'"$current_temp"')
QUERY_INPUT
```

Quoting "$current_temp" within single quote should pass the string as a quoted string, which is valid for SQL.